# Resizing images for different devices

Tags: android, imageview, android-image, image-scaling, image-size

I want to know how to make the images are properly sized for each device. I tried changing the values ​​in `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` in dp but when testing on a phone pictures are perfect but when testing on a tablet or 5" phone the images are distorted.

I want to know how to make each disposivito be scaled properly and look good.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you will never want to use specific numeric values for `layout_width` and `layout_height`.

A good solution is to use either `wrap_content` or `fill_parent`, depending on what you need. Also check out `android:adjustViewBounds` for the `ImageView` that is hosting your picture(s). This usually sizes images pretty well without distortion and needing specific values for every size layout.